# 'Make A Selection' Box not appearing in Crosstalk

Tags: r, shiny, dt, r-leaflet

While running a shiny application, the 'make a selection' box does not appear until you double click on the icon. Thereafter if you resize it, it disappears again. I have tried this in both Firefox and Chrome.

Here's the code I am using:

```
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, leafletOutput('cmap',height=600, width='100%')),
    column(6, dataTableOutput('cmapTable'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sDraft <- SharedData$new(df)

  output$cmap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(sDraft) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~lon, lat=~lat)
    })

  output$cmapTable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(sDraft, options = list(scrollX = TRUE),filter='top')
  },server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's the `df` data:

```
structure(list(mmsi = c(538004533L, 538004534L, 538004536L, 538005117L, 
538005118L, 538005120L), Name = c("STI GARNET", "STI TOPAZ", 
"STI ONYX", "STI LE ROCHER", "STI FONTVIEILLE", "STI VILLE"), 
    Dwt = c(51840L, 51840L, 49990L, 49990L, 49990L, 49990L), 
    lat = c(25.0050144, 11.213192, 1.26014328, 13.41435, 32.3204, 
    5.7550416), lon = c(55.05124, 121.773193, 103.914574, -18.28864, 
    -117.113571, 81.47743)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "mmsi", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(mmsi = c(538004533L, 
538004534L, 538004536L, 538005117L, 538005118L, 538005120L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame", vars = "mmsi", drop = TRUE))
```

I am on a MacBook Pro (macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6).